# Rails4 - How to add reference to an existing table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I believe following are the steps to add a reference.

```
$ rails generate model Country name:string
$ rails generate model User name:string gender:boolean birthdate:date country:references
$ rake db:migrate
```

Add - User belongs_to a Country and Country has_many Users in the models

But I have an already existing project where I want to add a reference.
Please confirm if this is the right way to add reference to an existing table.

```
$ rails generate model User name:string gender:boolean birthdate:date
$ rails generate model Country name:string 
$ rails generate migration AddCountryRefToUsers country:references
$ rake db:migrate
```

Add - User belongs_to a Country and Country has_many Users in the models

Hope there are no differences between the two approaches and the application doesn't explode later.
I just want to make sure if I am not missing something that happens behind the curtains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, there are no differences, just make sure you name the migration with the correct table name, for example, add a movement reference to table invoices:

```
rails g migration AddMovementRefToInvoices movement:reference
```

Comment: Thanks. Should it be movement or movements? rails g migration AddMovementRefToInvoices movement:reference

Comment: You are correct, singular is the correct form (edited)

Comment: you need to pluralize reference -- > `movement:references` otherwise this will think its an add_column migration of type reference, which is an `ActiveRecord::InvalidStatement` error